# usage for the verb prowled

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

> The owl prowled in the plain.
>
> It happened in the plain where the flying predator prowled.

Are these sentences using the word prowled correctly? I thought you would use it for land predators, but I am not sure how to use the word for flying predators.

Comment: Did you mean "owl" instead of "howl?" A howl is not an animal but a cry (sound) made by an animal.

Comment: It looks to me as though the writer is using the verb for effect, simply due to the similarity in sound between owl/prowl. As you noted, it is unusual to see "prowl" used to describe flying creatures - in fact, I've never heard it used that way before.

Comment: As a transitive verb, "The owl prowled the plain.", it seems appropriate. M-W to roam over in a predatory manner. That's exactly what owls do, flying as quietly as possible, back and forth, until they hear a sound. It is unusual, but it fits perfectly.

Comment: Did you write these examples? Or are you quoting them from somewhere.  You have to tell us the original source, and if possible link to it.